# Pandas.round() doesn't work on my dataset

Tags: pandas

Unfortunately pandas.round() doesn`t work on my dataset

```
 df.balance
Out[1]:
0 17173.71
1 17173.71
2 17173.71
Name: balance, dtype: float64
df.balance[0]
Out[2]: 17173.709999999999
df = df.round({'balance': 2})
df.balance
Out[4]:
0 17173.71
1 17173.71
2 17173.71
Name: balance, dtype: float64
df.balance[0]
Out[5]: 17173.709999999999
```

Python 2.7.10 and Pandas 0.19

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's actually most accurate representation of what 17173.71 could be:

```
01000000 11010000 11000101 01101101
01110000 10100011 11010111 00001010
```

which is 1.7173709999999999126885086298E4. You cannot represent 17173.71 exactly. It works fine.

You might be confused why you see 17173.71 when displaying pandas Series but 17173.709999999999 when displaying exact value. It is a result of pandas formating. Try:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.60f}'.format
```

Then try displaying Series again